# String Replace after Last Period

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, preg-match

Here I am getting the file name as `$fileName`

I want to store the file name as

```
filename_randomnumber.extension
```

If file name is file.jpg then it will be `file_randomnumber.jpg`

If file name is test.png then it will be `test_randomnumber.png`

I use the following code for that

```
$digits = 6;
$digits = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
$val = $digits.'_.';
$gen_path = preg_replace("([.]+)", $val, $fileName);  //replacing . with _randomnumber.
```

I am just replacing the . with  random number and _

But the threat is

If the file name has

```
test.image.png
```

Then the value will be `test_randomnumber.image_randomnumber.png`

What i need is i need to replace the right most . found in the file name.

So that the result will be `test.image_randomumber.png`

How can i do this

Comment: Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php and use substr to get the left and right parts, and then add your random number in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Tiny Workaround which will get your need.

Firstly Explode after last . 'period'

```
$fileName = implode('.', explode('.', $string, -1));
```

Secondly get the Extension in the right most of the `$fileName`

```
$ext = substr($string, strrpos($string, '.') + 1);
```

And in Mid your `$val` shall be concatinated

**So, Your Code must be**

```
<?php
$fileName = 'b.a.png';
$string = $fileName;
$fileName = implode('.', explode('.', $string, -1));
$ext = substr($string, strrpos($string, '.') + 1);
$digits = 6;
$digits = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
$val = $digits.'_.';
echo $fileName.$val.$ext;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) and [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
function getRandomFileName($fileName)
{
    $info = pathinfo($fileName);

    $digits = 6;
    $digits = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);

    if (isset($info['extension'])) {
        return sprintf('%s_%s.%s', $info['filename'], $digits, $info['extension']);
    } else {
        return sprintf('%s_%s', $info['filename'], $digits);
    }
}

echo getRandomFileName('test.jpg'); // test_838135.jpg
```

Comment: `$info['extension']` will fail if there is none.

Comment: @georg Updated, thanks. Leaving it to the OP to replace the `else` clause with an error or whatever not :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$genpath=substr_replace($fileName,"_".$digits,strrpos($fileName,"."),0);
```

1. `strrpos` gets the last position of `"."` in `$fileName`.
2. `substr_replace` inserts the random number with the underscore into `$fileName` before the dot.

Assuming the filename has already a dot inside.